# How to configure all exceptions to 'any' type

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, vetur

Recently on my typescript project, all catch blocks suddenly started to give the following Typescript compíle error:[image]

I dont know if it was some update on the config file, but how can I configure Typescript to consider all catched exceptions as `any` type instead of `unknown`

Comment: what changed? if they all changed at once, something changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you upgrade TypeScript recently?

Starting in [TypeScript 4.4](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#defaulting-to-the-unknown-type-in-catch-variables---useunknownincatchvariables), catch variables are now defaulted to the `unknown` type.  This can be controlled with the `--useUnknownInCatchVariables` option.

You can cast it as `any` if you really want to, but as always, this is considered a bad practice in TypeScript.

```
} catch(error: any) {
  if (!error.response.data.error) return
  ...
}
```

More information about this can be found in the [PR that implemented this feature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/41013).